# How to access a user's contact with Google Auth

Tags: python, google-oauth

I have access to a user's contacts, but am having trouble defining the correct "scope" for the requests. Here is an example of doing a valid call to get a user's info:

```
requests.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo", 
    headers={"Authorization": "OAuth %s" % token['access_token']}
).json()

{'id': '123454', 'email': 'hello@hello.com', 'verified_email': True, 'name': 'David', 'given_name': 'David', 'family_name': 'K', 'link': 'https://plus.google.com/113517799811778999421', 'picture': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-AWzSenGDgCs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAN311234572il0r4-RMKl1VC2234AmqQ/mo/photo.jpg', 'locale': 'en', 'hd': 'hello.com'}
```

How would I do the same for the "contacts" scope (which I reference in another call with: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a user's contacts by using the following url:

```
CONTACTS_DATA_URL = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/%s/full?max-results=20000" % email
```

Here is more information in the Google docs: https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts